# Weird visual behavior when clicking on time of comment on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

Whenever the date at which a comment was made is clicked, the screen scrolls down a little. I don't know why it is doing that. There is no real damage done, but it looks like a bug. It happens on all the comments made by any user. I guess it could be a browser compatibility issue. The scrolling down is such that the link date commented comes to the top of the screen.

Comment: Here's a comment to test it on.

Comment: The other thing is that clicking a date that was clicked last does not reproduce the effect.

Comment: @Sai: No, because the browser has already scrolled to that point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So the intended behavior is that even if the user clicks on a comment, scrolls through the page and then clicks back on the same, nothing should happen? If so, then it makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The timestamp is also a direct link to that comment.

When you click on it, the browser does what the link tells it to do: scroll to the comment. Normally you'd use it to provide someone with a link to that specific comment by right-clicking the timestamp and selecting 'copy link'.

In other words, this is not a bug, it is a feature.

Comment: Well it scrolls in such a way that the comment goes right to the top of the screen. So it looked weird. It makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Sai: that's just how your browser (and all others as well) implement "view *that part* of the document". They could also make dancing birds appear around it, but the "scroll to it" part is what most browser vendors implement.

Comment: yeah I get it that that's an intended behavior. thanks